# Add Image With Changeable Link in Custom Field

Tags: custom-field

In my WordPress site, I want A image with changeable link in bottom of every post. The Image will be fixed but links should be changeable. I want This changeable link option in the post editor of wordpress so that I an Change the link as different post-different link. This links are the same post but in different language from sub-domain website.

Please help. Sorry for bad English. Thank You.

Comment: Please post the code you have written and tested and tell us why it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us know what you have tried up till now to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this code with help from Google search. And it works fine. I added this code in single.php bottom of the post. Now, I simply add link in every post but image are same. Thanks. :)

```
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "imglink", true) ): ?>

<p><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "imglink", true); ?>"><img src="http://-------------.png"></a></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```